# Pandas Check Excel import for isnumeric() data in Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am importing data into Pandas from Excel and I need to verify that the data is numeric based on the Columns.

```
        month      value        dp        wd  ...      mg   fee      pr      comment

0  2013-07-31  208372.33   4206.84   4692.22  ...       0     0       0    some comment
1  2013-08-31  210669.77      0.00   1270.28  ...       0     0       0
```

There are about 20 columns and I only need to exclude the "month" and "comment" columns.

Is there something like:  df.iloc[:, 2: 18].isnumeric() or will this require a loop?

I would like to get a True / False response.

thank you.

Comment: You can do `df.info()`. `int64` and `float64` type means they are numeric.

Comment: unless I insert some text - they all come back as float64. need to confirm they are all float64?

Comment: No need - thats what info is usually used for, a summary. But keep in mind that `nan` also results in float64.

Comment: I have to confirm they are all numbers. I am importing excel data and cant allow any other data. this data comes from users so I can not trust it.

Comment: if they put in text it - returns an object. so need to confirm the dtypes are all the same. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way is `select_dtypes` and compare:

```
np.array_equal(df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns, df.columns[1:-1])
```

Comment: It always returns false?  why include the .columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply method to apply series methods to columns of a dataframe.

```
df2 = df.drop(["month", "comment"], axis=1)
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: x.str.isnumeric())
```